# How to make a rectangle disappear when another intersects with it?

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, collision-detection, game-engine

What I want is that if the sample touches the mfire, the mfire will disappear permanently. I don't know how to "undraw" a sprite if that's possible. :/ Thank you, people - desperatestudent

```
 foreach (Platform mfire in mfires)
 if (sample.rectangle.Intersects(mfire.rectangle))
      {
             //What to put here?

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is draw every frame.

So what you want, is in your Update method check if it intersects. If yes, remove it from the array.

Then, in your draw method, you simply draw everything in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an array or list where you save your objects, you can call a function in that array to remove an object.

So in your situation:

```
foreach (Platform mfire in mfires)
if (sample.rectangle.Intersects(mfire.rectangle))
{
    //put this here
    mfires.Remove(mfire);
}
```

I cannot tell whether you're using an array or a list, so this solution works if you're using a list.

Comment: Thank you. I used list here.

Comment: In that case it'll work, just remember to place the curly braces for the for-loop too.